# Can I remove or relocate a beam that acts as a rafter tie?

Tags: ceiling

I’m an converting our 20x25 detached garage to an in-law suite. I have a 12x20 beam spanning cross our loft. It used to hold the joist together, but I cut them off and opened the ceiling. My question is can I replace the beam with a collar tie, relocate the beam, or do I really even need it? You can see there is a jack stud holding the ridge board up, and the original building used 2 ridge boards.

[image]

Comment: I'd be seriously worried about the strength/stability of the roof already. But maybe an expert will come along who knows this stuff better.

Comment: In general people do not put up continuous pieces of lumber for fun. If they can get away not using it, they would have. What you removed is most likely structural and needs to be put back up.

Comment: Can you give us a description or sketch of what the roof structure looked like before you changed any of it?

Comment: @brhans, the only change was removal of the ceiling joists, the stubs of which are visible.

Comment: You can probably convert to multiple low collar ties if you get someone on site to look things over. I assume that you're looking to raise the ceiling a bit, which should be possible. We can't really say from here with the limited information we have.

Comment: Yes, the only thing I have removed is the joist. I plan to get an engineer out, so I will update you guys later. Thanks for the feed back

Answer (score 6):

Before you make any structural changes to a building it would be very wise to hire a "structural engineer" to make sure that you do not reduce the integrity of the building. Just removing braces that may be there so you can change the internal space in any structure, move any walls or load bearing wall could be a costly mistake for the building and for anyone inside the building. PLEASE, hire an expert to make sure that you do not do anything stupid or make a mistake that can't be undone. my 2 cents

Comment: Just seconding this answer.  You are radically changing the structure of this building and, it appears, doing so blindly.  Please STOP what you're doing, add some supports in areas where you have removed structure, and call in a licensed structural engineer to give you some guidance.  If you have failed to get a building permit for this work, then that is a huge mistake also.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot remove the beam and install a collar tie as sketched in the picture.

If the ridge beam was structural, then you might be able to remove it.

I suspect the other jack stud that you removed was structural too and should be replaced.

One collar tie for that size garage is not adequate. (Perhaps ties to every other roof joist (about 4’ oc) might work, depending on loads and size of roof joist.)

Comment: I don't see where a jack stud was removed.